# Not able to run Nunit in WindowsServer 2008

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, environment-variables, windows-server-2008

I'm experiencing a problem with Windows Server 2008 when running Unit Tests with Nunit.

Basically, In a Windows 7 machine I'm able to execute my Unit-Tests by following those steps:

1. I open a VS10 command prompt
2. I execute a bat script for adding to the PATH env. variable, some additional folders where my assembly (that contains unit-tets) can find additional DLL required at run-time. My assembly is not located in the same folder where some required DLLs are placed.
3. I run nunit-console (2.6.4) and it's able to execute the Unit Tests that are contained in my assembly.

In a Windows Server machine (2008 r2), I follow the steps listed above, but I'm not able to run unit-tests because It seems that Windows is not loading the required DLL from the additional folders I configured in the PATH env variable.
I tried also to change the PATH env variable globally for adding the additional folders, but it seems that the required DLL are not loaded from the PATH when nunit-console has been executed.

Are you aware of some limitation in Windows Server?
Do you know any work-around?

Thanks in advance.

Update :
As suggested by Charlie below, I verified that only the not managed assemblies are loaded from the folders specified on the PATH. So thanks a lot for clarifying this.

BTW, I'm still not able to understand why in WindowsServer I'm not able to run unit-tests: Execution Runtime: net-3.5 Could not load file or assembly 'MyAPP, Version=3.212.1002.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a91ab2fd56d8420' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assemblies you are referencing are managed assemblies, adding the location to the path has no effect. The path is not used in loading managed assemblies. The referenced assemblies must be in the ApplicationBase or on an additional ProbingPath that you have configured.

The other side of the coin is that any non-managed assemblies that your managed assemblies reference are found using the path.

Comment: Hi Charlie,thanks a lot for the answer.
The strange think I noticed is that in Windows 7, if I don't specify the PATH with the additional folders, I'm not able to execute Unit Tests. When I add to the PATH (via bat script in a console) the additional folders, I'm able to run unit-tests, because in this case the assemblies are loaded from the additional folders.



This doesn't happen in Windows Server 2008.
Do you know any work-around?
Please note also that the assemblies I'm referencing are managed assemblies.

Comment: Another point : Yes I verified that only the not managed assemblies are loaded from the folders specified on the PATH. So thanks a lot for clarifying this.

BTW, I'm still not able to understand why in WindowsServer I'm not able to run unit-tests:

Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Could not load file or assembly 'MyAPP, Version=3.212.1002.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2a91ab2fd56d8420' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Take a look at the Fusion log to see which dependency could not be found.

Comment: Yes, I had a look, but unfortunatelly all the logs entries are like : "The operation was successful.". So there are not errors.
I forgot to mention that in Windows7 I have installed both VS13 and VS10, but in Windows Server only VS10. Does it make some differences?